# Adding google map marker to screen based off a HTML select

Tags: php, mysql, html, xml, google-maps

Im looking to place markers on a google map based off of a select drop down. I have my my document relating to an XML document that has the results from a database and I want to grab the results from that xml document based on my select drop down. I want to then place those markers on the map. Any ideas on the best way to go about this? I would like to use php if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will only be able to use PHP for part of it,   to paint the markers on the map with google maps you need to use javascript.  Here is a very basic example of how to load up google maps and display a marker on it.  Obviously you would need to iterate through your data source and use that to populate the option values in the select list. If you are dealing with a lot of potential items, it may make sense to get the option values in a separate http request (using ajax for example).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Simple Map</title>
    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=3&amp;sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var map;

        var male = [[39.167107,-86.534363],[39.130554,-85.128891]]; 
        var female = [[39.167107,-84.534363],[38.130554,-83.128891]];

        function initialize() {
          if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {
            map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map_canvas"));
            map.setCenter(new GLatLng(39.167107,-86.534363), 7);
            map.setUIToDefault(); 

          }
        }  

        function addMarker(){ 
            var select = document.getElementById("choose_option");
            var currentValue = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;     

            if (currentValue == "Male")
            {  
                for (i=0;i<male.length;i++){
                    var markerPoint = new GLatLng(male[i][0], male[i][1]);
                    var marker = new GMarker(markerPoint, {draggable: true, bouncy: true});
                    map.addOverlay(marker);
                }
            }
            else if (currentValue == "Female")
            {    
                for (i=0;i<female.length;i++){
                    var markerPoint = new GLatLng(female[i][0], female[i][1]);
                    var marker = new GMarker(markerPoint, {draggable: true, bouncy: true});
                    map.addOverlay(marker);
                }
            } 

        }
    </script>
  </head>

  <body onload="initialize()" onunload="GUnload()">
    <div id="map_canvas" style="width: 500px; height: 300px"></div> 
    <select id="choose_option" onchange="addMarker()"> 
        <option id="1" value="">Choose</option>  
        <option id="2" value="Male">Male</option>
        <option id="3" value="Female">Female</option>
    </select>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This was a great help and thank you. However, my options are fixed to just male and female. when one or the other is selected I want only the male or female entries from the xml document to be placed on the map. Any more insight?

Comment: Can you paste part of your XML document as a reference?

Comment: `<markers>
<marker name="johnnyjacksin" gender="male" lat="39.167107" lng="-86.534363"/>
<marker name="philhubert" gender="male" lat="39.130554" lng="-85.128891"/>
<marker name="nancypotter" gender="female" lat="39.167107" lng="-84.534363"/>
<marker name="lindaellerbe" gender="female" lat="38.130554" lng="-83.128891"/>
</markers>` ------>so i want to return for instance only the male entries if that is what select option was picked

Comment: ok, I revised the code in my original answer.  You will need to figure out how to translate the XML file into the javascript arrays named male and female above (which you can use php for on the server side).  The rest of it should work as how you have described.